# getting java.lang.NullPointerException hadoop map-reduce program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am getting the following error while fetching data from db and loading into another table:

```
15/07/01 04:23:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1434100146148_0014_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: It's definitely a NullPointerException. Other than that, we cannot know anything more without the code that you are running

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Subba

the above issue got resolve .there was error in column name in my input sql query .my query is

```
select * from allTypes where **key** = ?;(correct) 
select * from allTypes where **id** = ?;(wrong ...no column as id)
```